# Oracle SQL: Transferring tables from one user to another

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, user-profile, copying

I created a new user called temp, with a password **temp**. I have another user called **Scott** that is identified by **tiger**. There are three tables in that profile that I'd like to copy onto **temp**. So i logged on to **temp** and punched in this (for the first table called **iowe**)

```
copy from  iowe@scott - create iowe - using select * from iowe;
```

Right after this when I hit **Enter**, it asked me the FROM password. I input **tiger**, and it threw an error. This is how it looks like:

[image]

So please tell me if there is a way to copy tables from one user to the other (I am sure there is)

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE temp.iowe
  AS (SELECT * FROM scott.iowe);
```

Check this link : http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php

Also note that temp user should have permission to access data in Scott schema.

EDIT:

Command to grant access to another user:
Login as Scott and run below command:

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on iowe to temp;
```

Check this link for details : http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/grant_revoke.php

Comment: It isn't working.. could you tell me how do I grant permission to have the temp profile gain access to the data of Scott schema?

Comment: Moreover, I don't think that command copies tables from two different user profiles. Even if it does, it isn't working. That is probably because i don't know how to grant temp permission to have access to Scott's schema. So, please provide me with the command to grant temp the permission. That link "http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php " doesn't have this information.

Comment: This command can copy table from one user DB user to another DB user. What do you mean by user profile? Can you paste the error you get when you run my command that wil be of big help. Also wanted to ensure that DB is oracle.

Comment: Added the script to grant access. Kindly replace proper table names in all my commands.

Comment: i'll do that in a bit. bare with me

Comment: So i logged into Scott and tried to execute the command "grant select, insert, update, delete on table1 to temp;" encountered error that read: SQL> grant select, insert, update, delete on table1 to temp;
grant select, insert, update, delete on table1 to temp
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Got the same error when i logged into the sysdba account..

Comment: ahh ... my friend ... I dont know the name of tables you want to copy, i just gave dummy table name. Please replace "table1" with the table name you want to copy.

Comment: Looking at your question , i think table name is "iowe". I have updated my post accordingly. Try now.

Comment: sorry..! i didn't mention that. I've tried that also. i replaced table1 with iowe, i encountered the same error. I'll try that again now, one sec

Comment: So, Grant was successful. now, i tried to execute creation of the table by "CREATE TABLE temp.iowe
  AS (SELECT * FROM scott.iowe);"

Hasn't worked

Comment: Can you paste the error as well? So after grant is executed successfully, you need to login as temp user and then execute "CREATE TABLE temp.iowe AS (SELECT * FROM scott.iowe)". In case it doesn't work pleae paste error also.

Comment: I go to the temp profile, and paste "CREATE TABLE temp.iowe AS (SELECT * FROM scott.iowe);" and it throws an error that reads: "ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'"

Same thing when I try this on the sysdba user.

When I go to the Scott profile, it throws an error that reads: "ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges"

Thnx

Comment: Thats an entirely different topic. "temp" user is not having rights to extend "users" tablespace :). "temp" user needs some serious treatment :). CHeck this : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01950_no+priviledges_on_tablespace_string.htm and hen try my sql.

Comment: brilliant! so i granted unlimited tablespace to temp, and them it worked like a charm! thanks a ton!

Answer (score -1):

```
copy from system/manager@localhost to scott/tiger@localhost create family using select * from family;
```